# .FINDSTRING Lotus Notes VBA

Tags: vba, excel, lotus-notes

So I'm using Excel to do some routines for me, and send an Email every mourning with the data the routine has extracted from SAP. This data includes coping 2 images, and a graph.

The problem is, that when I dont have notes logged in, the macro runs smoothly, but when it is already open, the ".FINDSTRING" cannot find the specific text I had inserted to paste the images.

I'm not sure why, I'm guessing I need a command to select the lotus and turn it active so the findstring could work, but I dont know what to do.

Here's a piece of the coding:

```
'________________________________________________________________________
    Windows(FileHoje).Activate
        Columns("A:N").Select
        Range("A2").Activate
        Selection.ColumnWidth = 10
        Columns("G:G").Select
        Selection.ColumnWidth = 2.14
        Columns("C:C").EntireColumn.AutoFit
        Columns("K:K").EntireColumn.AutoFit
    '________________________________________________________________________
    Selection.CopyPicture Appearance:=xlScreen, Format:=xlPicture

    Set NUIdoc = NUIWorkSpace.EDITDocument(True, NDoc)
    With NUIdoc

    .GotoField ("Body")
    .FINDSTRING "**1**"

    Windows(wb).Activate
        Sheets("Indicadores").Select
    '    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Tabela dinâmica1").PivotFields("Semana").CurrentPage = Range("AV23").Value
        ActiveSheet.Shapes("Grupo 3").Select
        ActiveWindow.WindowState = xlNormal
        ActiveWindow.WindowState = xlMaximized
        Selection.Copy

    .Paste
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    '________________________________________________________________________

    .GotoField ("Body")
    .FINDSTRING "**2**"

    Windows(FileHoje).Activate
    Dim LR As Integer
    LR = Range("H" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
    Range("H1:N" & LR).Select
    Selection.CopyPicture Appearance:=xlScreen, Format:=xlPicture

    .Paste
    Application.CutCopyMode = False


    '________________________________________________________________________
    .GotoField ("Body")
    .FINDSTRING "**3**"

    Windows(FileHoje).Activate
    Dim LW As Integer
    LW = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
    Range("A1:F" & LW).Select
    Selection.CopyPicture Appearance:=xlScreen, Format:=xlPicture

    .Paste
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    '________________________________________________________________________

    Windows(FileHoje).Activate
        Range("A9").Select
        Range("A2:N60000").Select
        Selection.Interior.ColorIndex = 2
        Range("O1").Select
        Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
        Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
        Selection.Interior.ColorIndex = 15
        Range("A2").Select
    Workbooks(FileHoje).Close SaveChanges:=True
    '________________________________________________________________________

            If attachmentFile <> "" Then
                If Dir(attachmentFile) <> "" Then
                    Set Attachment = .Document.CreateRichTextItem("Attachment")
                    .InsertText String(2, vbLf) & "File attached: " & Mid(attachmentFile, InStrRev(attachmentFile, "\") + 1)
                    Attachment.EmbedObject EMBED_ATTACHMENT, "", attachmentFile
                Else
                    MsgBox "Arquivo" & attachmentFile & " Não encontrado, não foi adicionado em anexo."
                End If
            End If
    '________________________________________________________________________
    .Send
    .Close
    End With


    Set NSession = Nothing

    Kill attachmentFile

     Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    End Sub
```

Comment: Wait, so with Notes closed, your Set NUIdoc = NUIWorkSpace.EditDocument() puts a Notes document into Edit mode?  That seems odd to me.

Comment: As this is VBA and he is using the NotesUIWorkspace class, he must be using the OLE classes (notes.*), not the COM classes (lotus.*). The OLE classes will start the client if it's not already running.

Comment: What happens if you comment out everything after the first call to  .GotoField("Body")?  Does the Notes client window get the focus, and is the cursor positioned to the start of the Body field?

Answer (score 1):

The problem here: If the Notes- Client is already open, then using "EditDocument" will not change window focus to the Notes- Client. You have to do this yourself.

In one of my projects I did it like this:

```
Set objWshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
objWshShell.AppActivate "Lotus Notes"
objWshShell.AppActivate "IBM Lotus Notes"
objWshShell.AppActivate "IBM Lotus Notes "
objWshShell.AppActivate "IBM Notes "
```

AppActivate matches the titles of open applications with the given string, if there is no matching app, then it simply does nothing...